# Get current recipient for envelope

Tags: docusignapi

My application use logic for work with current recipient with EchoSign (change recipient).
I need to be able retrieve current recipient for envelope usign DocuSign API. How it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) which is a great resource for anything API related.  If you go through the Quick Start section of the dev center you will see the **API TOOLS** section, which has free code samples that show you how to do things like Get Recipient Status.

[API TOOLS](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/quick-start/api-explorer)

[API DOCUMENTATION](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation)

The API Walkthroughs have an example of how to get the current recipient status.  Here is the full PHP sample:

```
<?php

    // Input your info here:
    $email = "***";         // your account email
    $password = "***";      // your account password
    $integratorKey = "***";     // your account integrator key, found on (Preferences -> API page)

    // copy the envelopeId from an existing envelope in your account that you want to query:
    $envelopeId = 'cbe279f6-199c-.................';

    // construct the authentication header:
    $header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 1 - Login (retrieves baseUrl and accountId)
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    $accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
    $baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
    curl_close($curl);

    //--- display results
    echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // STEP 2 - Get envelope information
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    $data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
    $curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes/" . $envelopeId . "/recipients" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
    );

    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nError text --> ";
        print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);

    //--- display results
    echo "First signer = " . $response["signers"][0]["name"] . "\n";
    echo "First Signer's email = " . $response["signers"][0]["email"] . "\n";
    echo "Signing status = " . $response["signers"][0]["status"] . "\n\n";
?>
```

Comment: I would find method which can do it without getting list all recipient and check status for each. But right now you solution is works. Thanks for response.